# Firebase RTDB Matchmaking

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In this blog from Firebase: https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/01/google-loteria-realtime-database they are talking about matchmaking.

This blog includes:

"When a player selects “Random Match,” their player ID is written to the location /queue/. A Cloud Function is set up to trigger when a new entry is created, and **it checks whether we have enough players to start a game.** If so, it creates the game at /games/*{gameId}*, and writes the gameId to each player's entry, like so: /players/*{playerId}*/gameId = *{gameId}*

Players listen to gameId on their own database entries, so they know when to transition to the gameplay screen.

Since there are a lot of players connecting simultaneously, and the Cloud Function is asynchronous, we once again used **a transaction to ensure that players are removed from the queue and placed into games atomically.** Making one game at a time atomically could create a bottleneck, so instead we **create as many games as possible in one transaction.**"

How do I check there are enough players to start a game and how to atomically create as many games as possible in one transaction?

Thank you

I use the same structure with queue, games and players.

Comment: "How do I check there are enough players to start a game" That should be fairly simple: read the node and check if the number of players exceeds the minimum for your game. Did you try that already? Can you show the code that isn't working?

Comment: I thought about to implement it. But when I create an listener oncreate on the node queue/$playerId and for example 100 players join at the same time. This handler would be executed 100 times and tries to create for instance 100x50 games (1vs1) games? 

How do I correctly check if there are enough players to create games? Do you have me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not very likely that someone has the code you need for a use-case in a shareable state, yet didn't share it yet. It's much more likely that we can help if you show what you already tried and where you ran into problems with that. Together these are known as a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and sharing that is the best way to increase the chances that someone can help here.